# Spring boot , arrays, JPA , database, angular

Tags: arrays, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to use array of 4 elements like (int a=5;
int b=6; int c=7; int d=8 ) and int []arr= {a,b,c,d} and put them in table  with different columns like:

```
column a                    column b              column c         column d

   5                           6                    7                8
```

Can someone give me an example class or give me a link to the same problem:

```
@Table(name = "columns")
int[]arr = {a,b,c,d}
@Column(name="a")
```

.......enter code here.
How to use column with elements here. I don't know

Something like:

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="infect")
public class Infect {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name= "coordinatex")
    private int coordinatex;
    @Column(name= "coordinatey")
    private int coordinatey;
    @Column(name= "firstx")
    private int firstx;
    @Column(name= "firsty")
    private int firsty;
    
    
    public Infect(int coordinatex, int coordinatey, int firstx, int firsty) {
        super();
        this.coordinatex = coordinatex;
        this.coordinatey = coordinatey;
        this.firstx = firstx;
        this.firsty = firsty;
    }
    
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getCoordinatex() {
        return coordinatex;
    }
    public void setCoordinatex(int coordinatex) {
        this.coordinatex = coordinatex;
    }
    public int getCoordinatey() {
        return coordinatey;
    }
    public void setCoordinatey(int coordinatey) {
        this.coordinatey = coordinatey;
    }
    public int getFirstx() {
        return firstx;
    }
    public void setFirstx(int firstx) {
        this.firstx = firstx;
    }
    public int getFirsty() {
        return firsty;
    }
    public void setFirsty(int firsty) {
        this.firsty = firsty;
    }
}
```

Like how to make this coordinatex, coordinatey, firstx,firsty, in arr[coordinatex,coordinatey,firstx,firsty] and put them in columns
not like private int coordinatex, i want them in array and then in columns

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: i edit it with more information

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
@Table(name = "columns")
int[]arr = {a,b,c,d}
@Column(name="a")
```

use this

```
@Table(name = "columns")
public class Yourclass {
   @Column(name="a") 
   public int a;

   @Column(name="b") 
   public int b;

   @Column(name="c") 
   public int c;

   @Column(name="d") 
   public int d;
}
```

Comment: is it possible from array to columns not a single parameter public int a

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="infect")
public class Infect {
       
    
   // Your implementation...

    public Infect(int[] arr) {
        if(arr.length!=4)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("arr lenght should be 4 in the format. [coordinatex,coordinatey,firstx,firsty]");
        this.coordinatex = arr[0];
        this.coordinatey = arr[1];
        this.firstx = arr[2];
        this.firsty = arr[3];
    }

   public int[] getArr(){
     return new int[]{coordinatex,coordinatey,firstx,firsty};
   }

    

}
```